# Laravel 5.1 pagination only show same list in each click on the link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to paginate list which are extracted from database but if each click on the show same page.

In controller:-

```
$admin = blog::paginate(8);
```

In view:-

```
<div style="text-align:center;">{!! $admin->render() !!}</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some more information or Controller code ??

Comment: Check your generates links and your routes. Paginate adds a get variable so it known which page to call. Maybe you overwrite it.